# Django: Why does this query get the pk numbers instead of the names when downloading an excel?

Tags: django, model

Beginner at django here: I have the following code for downloading an excel document from my homepage:

```
class ExcelDownloadAllView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        columns = ['Project Number', 'Assignee', 'Priority', 'Status', 'title','Summary', 'created_by']
        rows = BugTracker.objects.all().values_list('project_number','assignee','priority','status', 'title', 'summary', 'author', )
        filename ='All_Projects.xls'
        return create_sheet_response(filename, columns, rows)

def create_sheet_response(filename, columns, rows):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('All Projects Data') # this will make a sheet named Projects Data

# Sheet header, first row
row_num = 0

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font_style.font.bold = True

for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style) # at 0 row 0 column 

# Sheet body, remaining rows
font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
for row in rows:
    row_num += 1
    for col_num in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

wb.save(response)

return response

#models
class Developer(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="To be")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Assigned")
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("developer_list")


class BugTracker(models.Model):
    project_number= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    assignee=  models.ForeignKey(Developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=priority_choices)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    summary=models.TextField()
    status= models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=progress, default="Open")
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("bug_list")
```

It creates the excel file successfully, but it downloads the foreign keys from my models using the pk/id number instead of the name associated with that pk number. So in this example, the "assignee" and "author" fields show pk numbers related to models that I have. How can I fix this?

Also, is there way to download "DateTime Fields? Whenever I try adding "created_at/updated_at" field, it gives me an error "Cannot resolve keyword 'created at' into field. Choices are..." Thank you! Help with either question is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `.values_...` exactly for the reason you found out yourself: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: What is the alternative to get a list of tuples for excel? Just manually fill in the rows?

Comment: use `django-importexport` with a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of author you can use `author__FIELDNAME` eg `author__first_name` or `author__email`

For datetime fields i need more details, generally, doing such things is better using a proper serialization with marshmallow, pydantic or Drf serializers  so that you will able to customize the desired output. Then you pass the queryset to the serializer and you get back the serialized data as list of dicts.

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. It worked! I'm not using serializers yet. I'm building a simple bug tracker app without APIs (still new at this). What details/info do you need? Ok if you you're not sure since it's more of an optional field for me to include